# Localization inside private pod is always defaulting to English

Tags: ios, swift, localization, frameworks, cocoapods

I have a private pod inside a application. I am trying to localize the pod. You can see that in the below Image. [image]

I have added the localization file in the resource bundle of the pod.

[image]

After that I created an extension on String for localizing values inside pod.

```
extension Bundle {
    private class ClassForBundle {}

    static func frameworkBundle() -> Bundle {
        let frameworkBundle = Bundle(for: ClassForBundle.self)
        let bundleURL = frameworkBundle.resourceURL?.appendingPathComponent("ABC.bundle")
        print("Bundle url....\(String(describing: bundleURL))")
        return Bundle(url: bundleURL!)!
    }
}
```

```
extension String {
    func localized(withComment comment: String = "") -> String {
        return NSLocalizedString(self, bundle: Bundle.frameworkBundle(), comment: comment)
    }
}
```

When I am trying to localize string using the following code. It's always defaulting to English.

```
let localizedString = "Land For Lease".localized(withComment: "Land For Lease label")
```

value I am getting is 'US Land To Let' though my country and region in simulator settings is set to Spanish and Mexico. Is there anything I am missing that I need to do? Your help will be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It was pod cache which was creating the issue. I spend almost half day on it. Deleting the app from simulator and deleting derived data saved my life. I am keeping this question here so that it may helpful and time saving for someone in future in case he want to add localization to private pod or facing same kind of issue.